# Check if the Git commit was pushed in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I've got a commit "Test 123" and I need to check if this commit was pushed or not.

If not - I need to check the next logic:

If(The last commit with message "Test 123" wasn't pushed ){
then..... git push
}

Please help how to check it correctly in PowerShell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+extract+commit+message

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
# Depending on your workflow, possibly fetch first here.

$commitTitle = "Test 123"
$logOutput = git log '@{u}..@' --pretty=format:'%s'

if ($logOutput.contains($commitTitle))
{
    # do something, in your example, maybe git push
}
```

**Explanation:** the `git log` command says, show me all of my commits on my current branch that are not on the upstream yet. (Note the order here matters when using the 2-dot syntax. If you flip it and used `@..@{u}` you'd get all the commits that are on the upstream branch that aren't on your local branch yet.) Once you have all of the commits, format them to only output the commit *subjects* (sometimes called "titles" which is the first line of the commit message<sup>1</sup>). Then if any of those commit subjects are equal to the `$commitTitle` variable, you found it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note a commit subject is the first line of a commit message, but only if a multi-line commit message has a blank line after the first line. If someone improperly formats a commit message to have multiple lines without a blank line after the first line, then all lines will be considered part of the subject.

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/fscp-git-and-github-part-ii/modules/fscp-git-branching/cheatsheet) I read:

> Branches should be named something that describes the purpose of the branch. Note that branch names can’t contain whitespace: new-feature and new_feature are valid branch names, but new feature is not.

You are using `Test 123` instead of something like `Test_123`. Try another name.

Comment: Thanks, that's a commit name - not the branch name.

Comment: Like git commit -m "Test 123" and I need to check if the commit with the such name was pushed to the branch.

Comment: Not even a commit **name** (ID) - it's a commit *message*.

Comment: Yep, thanks! 
So I need to check if the last commit with such message was pushed...